# Formula to remain after running macro

Tags: vba, excel

I was wondering how I can have a formula stay on column J2:J600. The formula is `=R2` and would go all the way down to `=R600`. I thought I could manually put the formula in but every time I run my macro, the formulas disappear. Is there a way to embed the formula into the column? Thanks.

**EDIT**

```
Sub FormatCounsel()
    Sheet2.Range("J2").FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[0]"`
    Sheet2.Range("J2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("J2:J600"), Type:=xlFillDefault
End Sub
```

This is what I put in and I'm getting an error.

**EDIT 2**

Sorry I just realized that I want the formula `=R2` in cells `J2:J600`. Sorry if I caused any confusion.

Comment: Can we see the macro?

Comment: Hey chancea I just added the macro I will be using.

Comment: You want to put `=J2` in J2:J600? That is a circular reference. Are you sure of what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a big red flag in your code: *you're using circular referencing*! This means that you're saying J2 = J2. In other words, your formula refers to itself for a value, so it calculates to find the value, but to find the value it needs to calculate, etc...

Entering circular referencing *should* always give you an error when you manually enter circular referencing. However, when using VBA to enter the CR, I was only able to raise an error by setting `Application.Calculation` to `xlCalculationManual`, and then calculating the sheet.

You may have just made a typo, and that explains why there's circular referencing in your code, but I figured I'd explain it anyway. :)

*R1C1* formulas use relative references to refer to cells. So when you say `RC[0]`, you're saying that you want to use the cell in the same row and the same column. Let's see some examples. In our example, the formula will be in B2.

```
Dim r As Range
Set r = Range("B2")

r = "=RC"         '<~~~ the equivalent to what you used in your code. Refers to B2.
r = "=R[-1]C"     '<~~~ Refers to B1 (current row minus 1).
r = "=RC[1]"      '<~~~ Refers to C2 (current column plus 1).
r = "=R[1]C[1]"   '<~~~ Refers to C3 (current row and current column plus 1).
r = "=R[-1]C[-1]" '<~~~ Refers to A1 (current row and current column minus 1).
```

Now, as far as entering formulas into cells, it can be done all at once and very easily. Consider the example below:

```
Sub FormatCounsel()

Sheet2.Range("J2:J600") = "=RC[1]" '<~~ Each cell will refer to the cell to the right.

End Sub
```

Comment: Hey sorry to cause confusion. I meant to say that I need the formula `=R2` to go all the way down to `=R600` on column `J2:J600`

Comment: @user3688713 Ok. Since I've provided examples of how R1C1 works, I'm going to let you figure out how to apply it to this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Any time you write something else to those cells or clear them with the macro, you will lose those formulas.  You need to find the place in your code where you are overwriting or clearing them, and modify that code.  The other option is writing those formulas back to the cells at the end of the macro.  You can accomplish this with:

```
Range("J2").FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[0]"
Range("J2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("J2:J600"), Type:=xlFillDefault
```

Comment: I use buttons on another sheet for anyone else that uses the macro. I just ran this code and it ended up giving me zeros on the blank sheet where I use the buttons and not on the sheet where I have all my data.

Would I have to include `Sheet2` somewhere in that code?

Comment: If you don't have the sheet activated that you want this run on you need to use Sheets("SheetName").Range("J2")... instead of just the range reference.  And it will always be zeros if you are writing a formula in cell J2 to get the value from cell J2.  It would help if you clarified your question further, or posted your code so we can better help you.

Comment: change Sheet2.Range to Sheets("Sheet2").Range

Comment: Sheet2 is the actual name of the sheet under VBA. "Current" is what I changed the sheet name to.

Comment: then Sheets("Current").Range